# Functional testing of full application life cycle

Tags: php, functional-testing

I'd like to cover our application with functional tests. I got familiar with most of examples, but they don't suit me, because they are too simple and cannot explain me how to describe *dependencies* of tests. Let's say we have blog application and we would like to test creation of blog post. First, only authenticated and authorized users can create blog posts. Second, in order to create blog post they have to create blog itself. Third, in order to create blog they have to register account, etc. All this actions must be covered with tests as well, so there are dependencies between tests like

```
class SigningUpTest { ... }
class LoginTest { ... } // depends on SigningUpTest
class CreatingBlogTest { ... } // depends on LoginTest, here I should get something like session_id
```

In simple application I can just put all this cases in the 1 class and use @depends annotation of PHPUnit. It works perfectly until we have to decompose tests in a different classes since application becomes complicated.

How do you test complex applications?

Comment: Functional testing !== Unit testing. For functional testing, you're probably better using a tool like [Behat](http://behat.org/) or [Codeception](http://codeception.com/)

Comment: Sure. But the question is the same. Codeception shows too simple example when I have to set URL and make assertions. But the question is how do I setup complex tests with hundreds of pages? How do I setup dependencies of tests?

Comment: You build them up using codeception (or Behat) but if a test runs to hundreds of pages, then you're not testing correctly - a user will not work through hundreds of pages to achieve a result... you run a suite of `individual` tests, each designed for one specific piece of functionality; not one test that tries to do everything

Comment: In order to test *one specific piece of functionality* I have to do sometimes the same actions to *reach* this functionality. As I said above, I cannot test creation of blog post without creating this blog, without signing up, etc.

Comment: In terms of Codeception I'd like to inject the same instance of WebGuy in all tests in right order. Otherwise I have to login *every time* I'd like to test small piece of functionality, it looks wrong.

Comment: Read up about StepObjects in codeception; these are common actions used in a range of different tests; typically (for example) login would have its own individual test(s); but would also be a StepObject for a whole set of other tests that required the guy to be logged in